# Remove url space betwen words

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can i make url like this http://www.picxeto.com/wallpapers/310/Title%20Some be http://www.picxeto.com/wallpapers/310/title-som and also the text to be lowercase not capitalize

Comment: You have access to your server's server/vhost config files?

Comment: No, i hava a shared cpanel account.

Comment: Then you can't make text lowercase

Comment: But how can i remplace the %20 with - ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wallpapers/([0-9]+)/(.*)\ (.*)$ /wallpapers/$1/$2-$3 [L,R]
```

Comment: Nothing, also here is the rewrite rule                        RewriteRule ^wallpapers/(.*)/$ ./wallpapers.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^wallpapers/(.*)$ ./wallpapers.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

Comment: @BogdanCrișu You have to add the above rule before the rule that you already have. Also make sure `Multiviews` is turned off: `Options -Multiviews`.

Comment: And how i can make if i type something after http://www.picxeto.com/wallpapers/312/Trisha-In-Bodyguard like http://www.picxeto.com/wallpapers/312/Trisha-In-Bodyguard/something to stop here

Comment: What does "to stop here" mean?

Comment: I mean if somebody types something after picxeto.com/wallpapers/312/Trisha-In-Bodyguard like picxeto.com/wallpapers/312/Trisha-In-Bodyguard/something to ghet the not found page. Example RewriteRule ^dmca$ dmca.php [NC,L] for picxeto.com/dmca if i type something after picxeto.com/dmca i get the not found page

Comment: What does that have anything to do with removing spaces between words?

Comment: Nothing, i forgot to say that what, you suggested it worked and i want to know if this is possible.